# Composer cannot download files

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to use composer on command line :

```
php composer.phar update
php composer.phar install
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar selfupdate
```

Whatever I do I always receive the same error message:

> File could not be downloaded. Failed to open stream

**I am behind a proxy**. If I use a browser and type the same URLs as the ones that didn't work with command line, there is no problem.

What should I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using composer from behind an HTTP proxy, you can use the standard `http_proxy` or `HTTP_PROXY` env vars. Simply set it to the URL of your proxy. Many operating systems already set this variable for you.

eg:

```
 HTTP_PROXY="http://my-corp-proxy.mcdonalds" php composer.phar install
```

bonus points if you throw it into your bashrc if your on Linux/OS X or your environment settings for Windows.

To make it easier, you can just export the variable, then you don't have to type it all the time.

```
 export HTTP_PROXY="http://my-corp-proxy.mcdonalds"
 php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Excuse me I am really  a newbie concerning the network thing and proxy.. I have no access to the proxy because I work in a company, I am with windows 7... what is the url after the HTTP_PROXY ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos on Win7 to add an environment variable you can follow this guide: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html you need to define HTTP_PROXY as variable name and `http://your.proxy.address.or.ip/` as value. Then you must restart CMD for composer to see the changes.

Answer (score 10):

The right an easy way to run composer on windows under a proxy is opening the console (cmd), go to your project location and run this command:

```
C:\wamp\htdocs\myproject\> SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080 && php composer.phar install
```

PD: You must changes parameters like: username, password, proxy.yourdomain.com and 8080 to yours

I hope this help to you

Comment: Thanks for adding the full username and password parts to the url.

Answer (score 2):

And DO NOT set `https_proxy` (just `http_proxy`)!

Comment: because https_proxy defaults to http_proxy if not set