# composer self-update TransportException

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried to update Composer via:`composer self-update`
but it encounter the `Composer\Downloader\TransportException`
here is what I've got from `composer self-update --verbose` and`php -d "apc.enable_cli=0" composer.phar self-update --verbose`

```
    Updating to version .
    Downloading: 100%



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  "https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar" appears broken, and returned an empty 200 response



Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:192
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:62
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->copy() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/SelfUpdateCommand.php:73
 Composer\Command\SelfUpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:897
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:15


self-update
```

Comment: Try to remove it completely and get the latest setup instead of using update?

Comment: @user1850712 I've installed it 3 days ago but I think it has problem

Comment: not sure if this will help but watch this video for installing composer and laravel4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_OZA27Batc&list=PLLJSbW-UxRIzGwfnTT7GKYRfwT7hmeEFd

Comment: @user1850712 Thanks for your video but it didn't help me

Comment: `php composer.phar diagnose` does this command show you anything?

Comment: or maybe you can post it here and see if there's any help

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues?page=1&state=open

good luck~

Comment: @user1850712 That's a good solution to try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out what's the problem.
as I connecting to internet through proxy server so composer must be configured first and as [iconoclast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241142/iconoclast) explained in [PHP Composer behind http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy) I tried to add this variables to system environment path(of cource on windows):

```
HTTP_PROXY(value = my.proxy.address:port)
HTTPS_PROXY(value = my.proxy.address:port)
HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI(value = 0)
HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI(value = 0)
```

But after setting the last 2 variable these 2 tests in `composer diag` encountered with errors:

```
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri
```

finally by removing them and restarting my PC all of the scenario went on as it assumed to go.;)

**BTW thanks for your support**

Comment: Nice job.. ...how did you figure it or out?

Comment: @user1850712 I checked the `composer diag` command output which shows that's a problem.