# installing laravel via composer InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-4, composer-php

I want to install laravel 4.x and as you know I **must** use composer.
I've tried:
`composer create-project laravel/laravel d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel`

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable.


create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs][--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

I've downloaded laravel from [github repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and then tried this one:
`composer install`
and this time I got:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I'm Using:

```
Apache 2.4.7
PHP 5.5.6
```

installed by `xampp-win32-1.8.3-1-VC11` on win8 64bit

please help me

#### Thanks

Comment: Please run `composer diag` and add any findings to your question. Do you have to use any proxies?

Comment: @Sven  here is the result:  `    d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>composer diag
    Checking platform settings: FAIL

    The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
    Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues beyond slowness.
    Checking http connectivity: OK
    Checking composer.json: OK
    Checking disk free space: OK
    Checking composer version: FAIL
    Your are not running the latest version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer and it was all about the problem between composer and my proxy setting that caused the problem.

I've explained the problem and solution in [composer self-update TransportException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448896/composer-self-update-transportexception/20596804#20596804)

After that fix composer installed laravel 4 completely and without any problem.

**Thanks everybody**

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add the "--prefer-dist
" . So in your case, you have to use the:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

in order to make it work. So just remove all the files from: d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel and then try again by following the below commands to your cmd (I guess you are using Windows!):

```
cd d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

I think this should work for you just fine

Comment: It doesn't make any benefit and I've tried that when I started my laravel installation chalenge.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install composer without any errors? I think I've got the same error before and the problem was in the composer installation.

Comment: I've installed this via composer setup and it doesn't show any problem but as I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448896/composer-self-update-transportexception) there is a problem in downloading (or checking for) update