# Can't install Composer on Ubuntu behind proxy

Tags: php, ubuntu, proxy, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer, in order to use Laravel, but I'm behind the company proxy. The proxy is already configured in the system, so

```
wget --proxy-user=<my_user_name> --proxy-password=<my_password> https://getcomposer.org/installer
```

works (curl doesn't!), and I get the 270kB "installer" file.

Next, I'm trying to run

```
php installer
```

as the [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) says, but then I get the following error:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

The error repeats 3 times, then the program quits. If I put a "sudo" before the "php", then nothing happens (it gets stuck in the "Downloading..."), as if php was waiting for something. Using

```
printenv | grep proxy
```

I get

```
http_proxy=http://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
ftp_proxy=ftp://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
all_proxy=socks://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
ALL_PROXY=socks://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
socks_proxy=socks://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
https_proxy=https://<my_proxy_host>:<port_number>/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
```

Shouldn't it be working? I'm on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04. I was following [this tutorial](http://profmarcello.blogspot.com.br/2015/04/instalacao-do-laravel-5-no-ubuntu-1410.html), and I'm stuck on step 8 (i.e. I already installed Apache and PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9.)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy), because I cannot even INSTALL Composer! The OpenSSL in PHP is NOT the faulty 0.9.8 series (it's 1.0.1f). I've put export HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0 and export HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0 at /etc/profile. I have the proxy variables shown above. Perhaps the problem is at the CNTLM stuff? I'll look for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Composer behind http proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy)

Comment: I've seen this question, and nothing there worked here. Beyond that, it is two years old, and none of the softwares used are in the same version anymore.

Comment: Try `curl` instead of `wget`.

Comment: curl wasn't working. wget worked. What is not working now is "php installer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from some experts close by:

add 3 lines to /etc/profile

```
export http_proxy=http://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]
export https_proxy=http://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]
export ftp_proxy=http://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]
```

For a similar error (apt-get update was not reaching some repositories), I edited /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://[username]:[password]@[webproxy]:[port]";
```

take care to remove the "/" after the port number (it was already there).

Now it's all working.

Comment: apt does not support SOCKS proxies at all.  `Acquire::socks::proxy` means  set the proxy for all URLs starting with a `socks` scheme.  Since your `sources.list` does not have any `socks://` URLs, that line is entirely ignored.

Comment: Ok, removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Work in Windows 10!

Answer (score 2):

Just install it manually.

first download the file

`wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar`

then move it under /usr/bin to have it globally.

`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`

Should do the trick on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Still better than nothing. And it's indeed a possible solution for the current problem.