# curl error 5 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/stevebauman/location.json: Could not resolve proxy: my.proxyserver.net

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, proxy, composer-php

I use ubuntu 20.04
when I run `composer require stevebauman/location` in laravel project I get the following error

```
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 5 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Could not resolve proxy: my.proxyserver.net), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

In CurlDownloader.php line 377:
                                                                                                                                       
  curl error 5 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/stevebauman/location.json: Could not resolve proxy: my.proxyserver.net  
                                                                                                                                       

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

I connected to the internet on my mobile and then ran this command again I get the flowing error

```
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to my.proxyserver.net port 8080: Connection refused), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

In CurlDownloader.php line 377:
                                                                                                                                                                     
  curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/stevebauman/location~dev.json: Failed to connect to my.proxyserver.net port 8080: Connection refused  
                                                                                                                                                                     

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

how can I fix this error??
pleas help me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems composer wants to use a proxy server for the connection that is not available on the network. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30853193) on setting a proxy server for composer, look at your system environment variables for a variable `http_proxy` and note it's value for restore if needed.

Then clear the variable:

```
$ unset http_proxy
```

To restore:

```
$ export http_proxy=<YOUR_ORIGINAL_VALUE>
```