# How to config composer and git through proxy

Tags: git, composer-php

I have many problems with proxy in my enterprise , but I have the username and password , with SourceTree I don't have any problem to config them however I don't know how to config the proxy in Git or Composer

The errors while I was installing proxy was

```
Proxy http://http_proxy=proxy.url.es:8080;https_proxy=proxy.url.es:8080 [from Environment Variables] failed with errors:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Composer behind http proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy)

Comment: @Stony I have this in a variable called HTTP_PROXY