# "failed to open stream" Composer (for Symfony2) with company proxy

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've to work with Symfony2 and so I've to use Composer.

I'm working on a Windows 7 PC with WampServer 2.5.

At first the setup file from http://getcomposer.org can't install Composer because of the proxy (I presume).
So I've downloaded direclty the latest composer.phar and try to execute the commands with

```
php composer.phar
```

Then I try to install Symfony2 :

```
C:/wamp/www>php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Symfony/ "2.3.*"
```

And I have this exception :

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: unkown host

I found some solutions here : [Composer cannot download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files)

like using :

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyadress:8080 && php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Symfony/ "2.3.*"
```

(the network admin says me that there is no username and no pass...)

but I always have the same error.

I try some variations (without the port, with lowercases, etc.).

I'm sorry if the question is already answered somewhere, I didn't find any solution.

Thanks if you have an idea !

Comment: Run `composer diag` first to see what the problem might be. This tries to access some well known resources and will report on the kind of error if there is any.

Comment: I run what you said and I obtain this :
git settings : OK
http connectivity: FAIL
And then I got exactly the same error than with the installation of Symfony (error with packages.json, failed to open stream, etc.)

Comment: Copy&Paste the complete output into your question, please. Additionally, what happens if you ping the proxy domain?