# "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install a new laravel instance with the following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/larevel authii --prefer-dist
```

But I am encountering the following problem:
[image]

My internet connection is on proxy server: `192.168.20.9:8080`
Moreover, I am on windows platform `win8.1 x64` and `Xampp` with `PHP 5.6.11`, any help?

Comment: Have you told it to use aproxy for the download?

Comment: I just restarted my OS and the error was gone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell composer to use a proxy.

Linke here: [PHP Composer behind http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy)
and
[Composer cannot download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files)

Like:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://my-corp-proxy.mcdonalds"
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Why is this happening? I have this error now, nothing changed in my envirnoment, AT ALL.

Comment: Just an extra. On [Composer's troubleshooting page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode) it says something about ipv6 compatibility issues. Just disable ipv6, run composer and enable it again.

Answer (score 15):

Linux users can run this command to resolve this issue:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

[More Information](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-)

Answer (score 5):

The fix for me was found here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-.

I had to disable IPv6 on my network interfaces. After disabling that, composer worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that this also happens when changing the networks. If I put the comüputer to sleep and then continue connected to other networks this happens.
So either restart the computer or your docker. Seems to work for me. Had the issue 2 times already.

Answer (score 0):

**For windows user**
open cmd and put this command

```
set http_proxy= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx (YOUR_IP:PORT)
set https_proxy= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx (YOUR_IP:PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, on my Windows machine, I was installing phpmailer; So, I mistakenly wrote

```
composer require phpmailer\phpmailer
```

instead of

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

I just thought somebody may have made that same silly mistake I made. So please use forward slash instead of backslash.