# Error on Installing Laravel or Lumen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Whenever i install laravel i get this error. Is there a problem with my system or there is any firewell issue which is blocking the installation.
I am using ubuntu with PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli).

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                           
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
  error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed                                                  
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                            
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer have to use a proxy.

Linke here: [PHP Composer behind http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy) and [Composer cannot download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files)

It will be like :

`export HTTP_PROXY="http://my-corp-proxy.mcdonalds"`

And then :

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: is it safe to run such commands from office or i need to talk to my IT head.

Comment: No they are safe. The source is authentic.